# Logger in log4j is getting null

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have configured log4j in my project.The **properties file** is as follows:

```
# Log levels
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,LOGFILE
# Rolling File Appender

log4j.appender.LOGFILE = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=D:/nova/logs/log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append = true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=com.utility.CustomizeHTMLLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.LocationInfo=false

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=FATAL
```

so in my java code i am **initializing the LogManager** by passing the class name:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Admin Setting Manager");
```

**`"Admin Setting Manager"`** is the class name.
Then i am doing the following steps to get the root logger information and trying to save the log file in a new folder :

```
 DailyRollingFileAppender file1 = 
 (DailyRollingFileAppender) logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("LOGFILE");

        String username = createdUser.replace(".com", "");
  //createduser will have the username who is logging in the webpage

        String path = "D:/nova/logs/"+username+"/lg.log";
        file1.setFile(path);
```

Here I am trying to get the logged in username and trying to create a directory of the username and save the log for each user in their respective directory.

But the logger is NULL every time.I am not able to understand that why the logger is not getting initialized.

I googled it thoroughly but not able to get any solution regarding this.
So please help me get trough this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **static Logger  getLogger(Class clazz**)  Shorthand for
>   getLogger(clazz.getName()).
>
> **static Logger    getLogger(String name)**
>             Retrieve a logger named according to the value of the name parameter.

In your code you have given class name with spaces `Admin Setting Manager` you need to remove white spaces.

you have to chagne your code to,
1. `Logger.getLogger(AdminSettingManager.class)` or
2. `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("yourclassnamewithoutspace");`

Comment: but sometimes the logger have the value and is not tell and then after debugging the code fir some four five times the logger comes as null..so if this is cause of the white spaces then why it holds the value sometimes..? help

Comment: It will not hold value because it cannot able to predict your class because of white spaces, i have edited my answer with methods which we can use in logger class.

Comment: thank you...it helped..now the logger is not null..let me debug it some times and see if the logger gets null again...nut thanx a lot..:)

Comment: check are you assigning `null` to `private static Logger logger` somewhere in your program, instead of debugging have you tried to run and then is any `NullPointerException` come on logger object?

Comment: instead of debugging have you tried to run and then is any `NullPointerException` come on logger object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
```